# How to get additional details for PHPStorm warnings?

Tags: phpstorm

I got the following warning:

> Optimize background properties
>
> This inspection tries to find similar CSS properties, which can be transformed to shorter form (shorthand; padding for individual sides can be shortened to 'padding' shorthand if possible, etc).

on this line of CSS:

```
background: url('../icons/loading.gif') no-repeat right center;
```

Is there a way to know what PHPStorm wants me to do with my CSS declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspection is not triggered for just this line, can you provide a complete example? Maybe there is another `background` attribute in your style that can be merged into this one? Normally you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the inspection and see the results after applying it. If it's not what you want, just Undo.

Here is the example (before):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
background-image: url('../icons/loading.gif');
```

(after):

```
background: url('../icons/loading.gif') no-repeat right center;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: transparent;  
background-image:url("resimler/search.png"); //on line
```

Optimize background properties less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection tries to find similar CSS properties, which can be transformed to shorter form (shorthand; padding for individual sides can be shortened to 'padding' shorthand if possible, etc). //I received this warning
as solution 
-webkit-background: transparent;  I did and fixed :)